# unknown Opcode '.pword'

Tags: c, gcc, arm, pic, opcode

When I compile my code I am getting a unknown Opcode '.pword' error.  The only line of code in my project that has .pword is:

```
do {
    __asm__ volatile (" .pword 0xDA4000");
    Nop();
} while(0)
```

Commenting the line out does nothing.

I searched `.pword 0xDA4000` and know it is supported by the IDE MPLab for PICs.

In my case the IDE I am using is CrossStudio for a STMf32f2xx chip.

I have the updated CrossStudio which comes with binutils 2.21 and gcc 4.6.0

I initially had a problem with compiling unnamed structs and unions but adding `-fms-extensions` into additional C compiler options fixed it.

I dont know if I need to do something similar to fix Opcode '.pword' error.

could it just be that .pword is only a PIC opcode?

Comment: As you run into further pic specific issues Electronics.Stackexchange.com has quite a few questions and quite a few experts. Just an aside if we can be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MPLAB ASM30 assembler the `.pword` declare 24 bit constant in code memory. It can be also any MPLAB ASM30 instruction.

Check: [MPLAB ASM30 assembler](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Asm30_Link_Util_51317e.pdf)

Comment: Ok, so it sounds that .pword is a unique opcode specific to the MPLAB assembler.

Comment: @microb: No, .pword` isn't opcode. The meaning of `.pword` (it is a constant type) is 24 bit constant declaration in code memory and that constant can be opcode.

Comment: oh, like a int float word etc

Comment: @microb: or even function call. :)

Comment: still unsure why im getting compiler issues. I'm cant find anything other then the code above that has pword.

Comment: @microb: sure, `.pword` is specific for 24 bit RISC DSPs.

Comment: thanks for your help looks like have to look into it a bit more.